# how to put element in a grouped 2d map which is used as a cache

Tags: java

my map is like-

```
Map<String,Map<string,Object>
```

sample data---

```
>  mycompany1----1st client----clientobject1
>     mycompany1----2nd client---clientobject2
>     mycompany2----1st client---client object 3
>     mycompany2----2nd client---client object 4
```

like this. so i need to group the data by the 1st key("company name").
i wantto store those data into some cache also.
but how to put data into that map so that it will be stored in grouped manner.
google multimap groupped data, but its not 2d map.

Comment: i want to put data like--map.put("company1","client1",object1). and it should be placed in proper group internally.

Comment: this solution won't work for you? @user

Answer (score -1):

Following code may help you, Which takes  `put` method with 3 params,

```
public class MyMap extends HashMap<String,Map<String,Object>>{

    public void put(String key,String c,Object v) {
        if(!this.keySet().contains(key)) {
            this.put(key, new HashMap<String,Object>());
        }
        Map<String,Object> obj = this.get(key);
        obj.put(c, v);
    }
    public static void main(String[]  args) {
        MyMap map = new MyMap();

        map.put("1","2","3");
        map.put("1","3","3");
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

Out put:

```
{1={2=3, 3=3}}
```

Always use bean classes to work with entities.